# Comma separated list with "and" in place of the last comma

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

I want to create a comma separated list in C# with the word "and" as last delimiter.

```
string.Join(", ", someStringArray)
```

will result in a string like this

```
Apple, Banana, Pear
```

but instead I want it to look like this:

```
Apple, Banana and Pear
```

Is there a simple way to achieve it with Linq and **without** using loops?

Comment: Do the items have to appear in the same order they currently are, or can we re-arrange them?

Comment: They should be in the same order.

Comment: `and without using loops` -- as the answers prove, you don't need explicit loops for this. However, loops are hardly evil, and LINQ is really just generating the loops for you.

Comment: If you're asking to do this without loops, you're going to get answers that are not very readable.

Comment: I know that Linq internally generates loops. However, from the standpoint of readability I find Linq better. Once you get into LinqToSql, you can't live without it anymore ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do a Join on all items except the last one and then manually add the last item:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DumpResult(new string[] { });
            DumpResult(new string[] { "Apple" });
            DumpResult(new string[] { "Apple", "Banana" });
            DumpResult(new string[] { "Apple", "Banana", "Pear" });
        }

        private static void DumpResult(string[] someStringArray)
        {
            string result = string.Join(", ", someStringArray.Take(someStringArray.Length - 1)) + (someStringArray.Length <= 1 ? "" : " and ") + someStringArray.LastOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a check on the amount of items and decides if it's necessary to add the 'and' part.

Comment: Nice, but what if the list contains fewer than two items?

Comment: Then, we would need to use this: string days = string.Join(", ", notSentDays.Take(notSentDays.Count - 1)) + (notSentDays.Count == 1 ? "" : " and ") + notSentDays.Last();

Comment: I'd rather use the `string, string[], int, int` overload than the `IEnumerable<string>` overload.

Comment: If the array has one item you end up with an empty string.

Comment: @juharr nope.. I've tested it. With one item it just displays the item. Doesn't add a ',' or 'and'.

Comment: @WouterdeKort My bad.  I missed a paren when I read it.  Though you might want to change that to `LastOrDefault` to avoid an exception when the collection is empty.

Comment: Really nice! I implemented it as an extension method like this:



        `public static string BuildSentenceFromList(this List<string> list, string normalSeperator = ", ", string finalSeperator =  " and ")
        {
            var result = string.Join(normalSeperator, list.Take(list.Count - 1)) + (list.Count <= 1 ? "" : finalSeperator) + list.LastOrDefault();
            return result;
        }`

Answer (score 13):

One possible solution:

```
var items = someStringArray; // someStringArray.ToList() if not a ICollection<>
var s = string.Join(", ", items.Take(items.Count() - 1)) +
        (items.Count() > 1 ? " and " : "") + items.LastOrDefault();
```

Note that this statement can iterate `someStringArray` multiple times if it doesn't implement `ICollection<string>` (lists and arrays implement it). If so, create a list with your collection and perform the query on that.

Comment: Works perfectly with 0, 1 and 2+ entries. Nice!

Comment: @JonB: What do you mean by "working perfectly with 0 entries". What should happen?

Comment: @MarkByers - it returns "", rather than causing an exception or returning something like "," or "and".

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to achieve it with Linq and without using loops?

Not possible without loop. For loop will work best. LINQ queries will use multiple loops.

```
    string Combine (IEnumerable<string> list)
    {
        bool start = true;
        var last = string.Empty;
        String str = string.Empty;

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            if ( !start)
            {
                str = str + " , " + item; 
                last = item;

            }
            else
            {
                str = item;
                start = false;
            } 

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last))
        {
            str = str.Replace( " , " + last, " and " + last);
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Well, multiple loops could get a performance issue if the list was long enough. Since there are roughly 5 entries, performance does not matter. The reason I use Linq is to avoid spaghetti code. There are about 10 people working on this project, so we can't exchange performance for readability like this. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Devils, If there are multiple entries Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`. Otherwise this is most efficient solution than any other `LINQ` query. I always try to do everything (as it is readable) in LINQ, but when performance issues comes, It is easy to write worst code using LINQ>